# Get current FullCalendar Time after scrolling

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I know you can scrollToTime dynamically and scrollTime sets it initially, but how do I get the updated time after scrolling in the timeline view? For example I scroll in timeline and first visible time I see is 8:47 AM, is there a function to get this new time?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not, at this time. Consider making a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features).